# Trying to read json from api in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to display maxPlayers from api https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/20151421, but i get 0 in result, and I should get 200 because maxPlayers in api = 200.

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

```
 <button @onclick="FetchData">lets go</button>

@if (todo != null)
{
    <p>maxPlayers: @todo.maxPlayers </p>
}

@code 
{
    public Attributes todo;
    public HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public async Task FetchData()
    {
        todo = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Attributes>("https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/20151421");

    }

    public class Attributes
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public int port { get; set; }
        public int players { get; set; }
        public int maxPlayers { get; set; }  // <-- this 
        public int rank { get; set; }
        public List<double> location { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Details details { get; set; }
        public bool @private { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
        public int portQuery { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string queryStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I would assume that EVERYTHING is empty, no?  What does the object contain right after being loaded, using a breakpoint?

Comment: With an api without a nested structure, like here https://catfact.ninja/fact, I have no problem with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the Json Data It has

- Top Level members Like `Data`
- `Type`, `Id` and Then `Attributes`

I suggest you to create a modal class like this

```
public class ServerResponse
{
    public ServerData Data { get; set; }
}

public class ServerData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Attributes
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

Check out this Link it will help you to create modal classes automatically as per the requested JSON

https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Already tried it. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: https://codeshare.io/8pAKOE

Comment: ``<p>maxPlayers: @todo.data.attributes.maxPlayers </p>``

``todo = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootobject>("https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/20151421");``

Make this Changes in the code u will get the result
actuall your are referring Attributes u should Refere RootObject

Comment: I edit code just as you say and now it looks like this. https://codeshare.io/8pAKOE
Now i have error in this line:
 todo = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootobject>("https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/20151421");

Comment: Please visit this link there i have create workable code Click the button you will get the data

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckwIYlbIIhlJkhUm

Comment: Damn. I forgot change 'public Attributes todo' to 'public Rootobject todo'. 
Thank you for help me, have a nice day.